# Is dividing the median (50th percentile) by 2 an acceptable approximation of the 25th percentile?

Tags: percentile

So for example, if the median is equal to 0.840335, could I approximate the 25th percentile as $0.840335 / 2 = 0.4201675$?

Would this be possible if one assumes the underlying data is normally distributed?

Comment: Usually not.  That is only half-way to zero, it is not half-way to the rest of the data.

Comment: The median height of American adults is probably between 5 feet and 6 feet. Would you believe that the 25th percentile of the heights of American adults is between 2.5 and 3 feet?

Comment: The median of $-3, -1, +1, +3$ is $0$. Half of $0$ is still zero

Comment: If you assume the underlying data are normally distributed, the median is the mean and the 25th percentile is the mean minus about $0.67449$ times the standard deviation. But if the mean and median are different, the data aren't normally distributed.